# rgba pixel calculation for overlays mix

Tags: image-processing, pixel, rgba

I got (r, g, b, a) pixels.

Need to add an overlay.
Overlay is black + variable alpha channel.
(0,0,0, alpha), like this one : [image]

what calculation should I do ?

I can't find something working great

Here's samples what I'm getting :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

[image]

Comment: o stands for output, a stands for added image, b for background image, note that the resulting alpha is 1